# Truncating rows based on column value in mysql

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have have a MySQL table with many rows that I want to limit in a specific way. Each row has a column, `userID`, that is indexed but is not unique. Each row also has a datetime column for `createDate`.

I'd like for the table to never contain more than X number (say, 1000) of rows for a given `userID`. So, anytime a row is inserted, if that means that there are now greater than X rows `where userID = Y` then the DB would delete a row based on the value of `createDate`.

Is this possible to achieve inside the database only? What performance concerns should I have about this kind of approach?

Comment: Are you looking to set something up as a scheduled stored proc to periodically prune your table? If not, you could probably do just fine with setting up an insert trigger to check if the `count` is 1000, and delete the earliest row for that userID upon insert.

Comment: @RToyota It should be something that runs as often as necessary so that no user, `userID`, ever has more than X records for any appreciable amount of time. So, maybe the insert trigger is the better option. We could use a script or stored proc to get the table to an initial state where no user has more than X rows.

Comment: I think what you are looking is an AFTER INSERT trigger.